# How to pass sys.argv[n] into a function in Python

Tags: python, function, argv, sys

I am trying to pass "sys.argv[1]" into a function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env/ python
import sys
def main():
    test(sys.argv[1])
def test(sys.argv[1]):
    print "Hello " + sys.argv[1]

./arg.py World

File "./arg.py", line 5
def test(sys.argv[1]):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Not sure where to go from here after scowering the Interwebs for a few hours. I have also tried to set the "sys.argv[1]" to a variable and tried passing that into the function and still no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sys.argv[1]` returns a string, so you can't add that as a parameter/argument.

I don't see why you would need this, just put no arguments at all:

```
def test():
    print "Hello " + sys.argv[1]
```

---

You may have also gotten mixed up. Argument names do not need to be the same name as what you would use when calling the function. For example, if I had `n = 5`, the function does not need to have an argument called `n`. It can be anything.

So you can do:

```
def test(myargument):
    print "Hello " + myargument
```

---

I'm just going to give you a quick little "tutorial" on arguments.

```
def myfunc():
    print "hello!"
```

Here we have a function. To call it, we do `myfunc()`, yes? When we do myfunc(), it prints "hello!".

Here is another function:

```
def myfunc(word):
    print word
```

This function takes an argument. So when we call it, we **have** to add an argument. Here's an example of calling the function:

```
def myfunc(word):
    print word

myword = 'cabbage'
myfunc(myword)
```

Notice how `'cabbage'` is set in the `myword` variable. It does **not** have to be the same as what we called the argument in the function. Infact, we don't even have to create a variable if we need. We can just do `myfunc('cabbage')`.

Also, in this example, you can only input **one** argument, as when we `def`ined the function, we only used one parameter. If you add two, you'll get something like `myfunc takes one argument (two given)`.

We called the argument `word` so we can use that in the function. Notice how I have `print word` and not `print myword`. It's as if we did `word = myword`, but instead of doing that step, we use the argument name.

Comment: Okay, basically what I am trying to do with the arguments, is pass a few arguments through that will be called quite a few times. Should I use raw_input / input to set those variables?

Comment: @GregRobertDutertre I think you're misunderstanding the point of arguments

Comment: Most likely. I also think I may be going about re-learning Python the wrong way as well.

Comment: @GregRobertDutertre I added some more to my answer. I hope this helps!

Comment: @GregRobertDutertre Good to hear! If you have any further questions, go ahead and ask

Answer (score 11):

I think you misunderstand the declaration and call of a function. In your program,there is only declaration,missing the calling statement.
As for passing parameters from command line,here is an example which I prefer:

```
import sys
def hello(v):
    print 'hello '+v

def main(args):
    hello(args[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

The program start to execute from the line 'if **name** == '**main**'  by calling the function defined previously and passing the sys.argv as parameter